# Splitting of Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where Dates are getting split based on Lookup from another table.

Here BillDetails and ClientFiscal are Source Table and BillDetailNormalized is Target Table.

For first record in BillDetailNormalized ServiceBeginKey will be from Billdetail Table i.e. 2011-11-09 and ServiceEndKey will depend upon two factors:

If no corresponding Enddate is present in ClientFiscal then it will be month end

else will be that corresponding date
Here from shared example its present in ClientFiscal table , so it will be 2011-12-10

Next record ServiceBeginKey will be 2011-12-11 and ServiceEndKey will be 2011-12-31 as no corresponding record is present in ClientFiscal table for that month

```
CREATE TABLE BillDetails
(
ClientKey INT,
BillDetailKey INT
,ServiceBeginKey DATETIME   
,ServiceEndKey DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO BillDetails VALUES (9,296643,'2011-11-09','2012-01-10');


CREATE TABLE ClientFiscal
(
ClientKey INT,
FiscalBeginKey DATETIME,
FiscalEndKey DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO ClientFiscal VALUES (9,'2011-11-13','2011-12-10');
INSERT INTO ClientFiscal VALUES (9,'2011-12-11','2012-01-07');
INSERT INTO ClientFiscal VALUES (9,'2012-01-08','2012-02-04');


CREATE TABLE BillDetailNormalized
(
BillDetailsNormalizedKey INT,
BillDetailKey INT,
ClientKey INT,
ServiceBeginKey DATETIME,
ServiceEndKey DATETIME
);


INSERT INTO BillDetailNormalized VALUES (443171,296643,9,'2011-12-09','2011-12-10');
INSERT INTO BillDetailNormalized VALUES (443172,296643,9,'2011-12-11','2011-12-31');
INSERT INTO BillDetailNormalized VALUES (443173,296643,9,'2012-01-01','2012-01-07');
INSERT INTO BillDetailNormalized VALUES (443174,296643,9,'2012-01-08','2012-01-10');
```

Comment: Please add your current query, its results, and your desired results, they will make this question much easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table #BillDetails
drop table #ClientFiscal
drop table #BillDetailNormalized

CREATE TABLE #BillDetails
(
ClientKey INT,
BillDetailKey INT
,ServiceBeginKey DATETIME   
,ServiceEndKey DATETIME
);


CREATE TABLE #ClientFiscal
(
ClientKey INT,
FiscalBeginKey DATETIME,
FiscalEndKey DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE #BillDetailNormalized
(
BillDetailsNormalizedKey INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
BillDetailKey INT,
ClientKey INT,
ServiceBeginKey DATETIME,
ServiceEndKey DATETIME
);


INSERT INTO #BillDetails VALUES (9,296643,'2011-11-09','2012-01-10');

INSERT INTO #ClientFiscal VALUES (9,'2011-11-13','2011-12-10');
INSERT INTO #ClientFiscal VALUES (9,'2011-12-11','2012-01-07');
INSERT INTO #ClientFiscal VALUES (9,'2012-01-08','2012-02-04');

INSERT INTO #BillDetailNormalized (BillDetailKey, ClientKey, ServiceBeginKey, ServiceEndKey)
SELECT X.BillDetailKey, X.ClientKey, X.FiscalBeginKey, X.ServiceEndKey 
FROM (
       SELECT B.BillDetailKey,
              C.ClientKey,
               C.FiscalBeginKey,              
              'ServiceEndKey' =
              CASE 
                 WHEN  B.ServiceEndKey IS NULL THEN DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, B.ServiceEndKey) + 1, 0))
                 ELSE  B.ServiceEndKey            
              END             
       FROM #ClientFiscal C
       LEFT JOIN #BillDetails B
       on C.ClientKey = B.ClientKey
       ) X
select *
from #ClientFiscal

select *
from #BillDetailNormalized
```

Comment: Output is different then expected.I was expecting 4 records in Target (BillDetailNormalized) but currently there are 3.Althogh thnx for time!!!

Comment: This is an example that demonstrates joining and the case statement.  You should be able to modify it to meet your needs.